# Como faço pra realizar mais de uma consulta ao banco de dados em uma única requisição .GET na mesma rota no NODE.JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, http-request, get, route

Estou criando uma API para um projeto pessoal, e preciso fazer 2 consultas ao banco de dados em uma mesma requisição GET. Meu código está assim:

```
module.exports = {
    async listarAnual(req, res, next){
        const ano = req.body.ano;

        const valores = {
            entradas: 0,
            saidas: 0,           
        }

        con.getConnection((error, conn) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).send({error : error})              
            }else{
                var sqlEntradas = `
                    select d.nome_descricao_entrada, sum(e.valor_entrada) from entrada  as e
                    inner join descricao as d on e.id_descricao_entrada = d.id_descricao_entrada
                    where Year(e.data_entrada) = ? 
                    group by d.id_descricao_entrada
                    order by d.nome_descricao_entrada asc;            
                `;

                var sqlSaidas = `            
                    select d.nome_descricao_saida, sum(s.valor_saida) from saida  as s
                    inner join descricaosaida as d on s.id_descricao_saida = d.id_descricao_saida
                    where Year(s.data_saida) = ? 
                    group by d.id_descricao_saida
                    order by d.nome_descricao_saida asc;            
                `;
          
                valores.entradas = conn.query(sqlEntradas,ano, function (error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) {
                        return res.status(500).send({ error: error });      
                    } else {      
                        return res.status(200).send({ entradas: results });                 
                    }      
                });

                valores.saidas = conn.query(sqlSaidas, ano, function(error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) {
                        return res.status(500).send({error: error});
                    } else {
                        return res.status(200).send({saidas: results});
                    }                
                });              
            }            
            
            return res.status(200).send(valores);
        });          
    }
}
```

O resultado dessa requisição está sendo esse:

```
"entradas": {
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 0,
    "next": null,
    "sql": "\n            \n            select d.nome_descricao_entrada, sum(e.valor_entrada) from entrada  as e\n            inner join descricao as d on e.id_descricao_entrada = d.id_descricao_entrada\n            where Year(e.data_entrada) = 2019 \n            group by d.id_descricao_entrada\n            order by d.nome_descricao_entrada asc;\n            \n            ",
    "values": 2019,
    "_queryOptions": {
        "rowsAsArray": false,
        "sql": "\n            \n            select d.nome_descricao_entrada, sum(e.valor_entrada) from entrada  as e\n            inner join descricao as d on e.id_descricao_entrada = d.id_descricao_entrada\n            where Year(e.data_entrada) = ? \n            group by d.id_descricao_entrada\n            order by d.nome_descricao_entrada asc;\n            \n            ",
        "values": 2019
    },
    "namedPlaceholders": false,
    "_fieldCount": 0,
    "_rowParser": null,
    "_fields": [],
    "_rows": [],
    "_receivedFieldsCount": 0,
    "_resultIndex": 0,
    "_localStream": null,
    "_connection": null
},
"saidas": {
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 0,
    "next": null,
    "sql": "\n            \n            select d.nome_descricao_saida, sum(s.valor_saida) from saida  as s\n            inner join descricaosaida as d on s.id_descricao_saida = d.id_descricao_saida\n            where Year(s.data_saida) = 2019 \n            group by d.id_descricao_saida\n            order by d.nome_descricao_saida asc;\n            \n            ",
    "values": 2019,
    "_queryOptions": {
        "rowsAsArray": false,
        "sql": "\n            \n            select d.nome_descricao_saida, sum(s.valor_saida) from saida  as s\n            inner join descricaosaida as d on s.id_descricao_saida = d.id_descricao_saida\n            where Year(s.data_saida) = ? \n            group by d.id_descricao_saida\n            order by d.nome_descricao_saida asc;\n            \n            ",
        "values": 2019
    },
    "namedPlaceholders": false,
    "_fieldCount": 0,
    "_rowParser": null,
    "_fields": [],
    "_rows": [],
    "_receivedFieldsCount": 0,
    "_resultIndex": 0,
    "_localStream": null,
    "_connection": null
}
```

Já tentei colocar os return que cada valor recebe ser apenas um "return results", mas continuou retornando a mesma coisa. Mas se eu apagar  o `return res.status(200).send(valores);` la no final, ele retorna os dados que eu espero apenas da primeira consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para alcançar o resultado desejado é necessário colocar as suas consultas em ordem e de maneira que sejam executadas após o callback da query, de forma que é necessário apenas reorganizar o seu código

Segue um exemplo de como pode ser feito:

```
module.exports = {
    async listarAnual(req, res, next) {
        const ano = req.body.ano;
    
        const valores = {
            entradas: 0,
            saidas: 0,           
        }
    
        con.getConnection((error, conn) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).send({error : error})              
            } else {
                var sqlEntradas = `select d.nome_descricao_entrada, sum(e.valor_entrada) from entrada  as e
                inner join descricao as d on e.id_descricao_entrada = d.id_descricao_entrada
                where Year(e.data_entrada) = ? 
                group by d.id_descricao_entrada
                order by d.nome_descricao_entrada asc`;
                var sqlSaidas = `select d.nome_descricao_saida, sum(s.valor_saida) from saida  as s
                inner join descricaosaida as d on s.id_descricao_saida = d.id_descricao_saida
                where Year(s.data_saida) = ? 
                group by d.id_descricao_saida
                order by d.nome_descricao_saida asc`;
            
                conn.query(sqlEntradas,ano, function (error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) {
                        return res.status(500).send({ error: error });      
                    } else {      
                        valores.entradas = results;
                        conn.query(sqlSaidas, ano, function(error1, results1, fields1) {
                            if (error1) {
                                return res.status(500).send({error: error1});
                            } else {
                                valores.saidas = results1;
                                res.status(200).send(valores);
                            }
                        });
                    }  
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```