# Insert no banco de dados SQL com NODEJS

Tags: node.js, chatbot

Tenho o seguinte codigo

```html
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO user (Usuario, Senha) VALUES ("+msg.chat.id + "," + msg.chat.2 + ")";
 
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
});
```

ele insere no banco de dados o usuário e senha, o problema e que ele não verifica se já esta cadastrado, e mesmo já tendo o cadastro ele insere novamente o mesmo registro , como faço para isso não acontecer?

Comment: Vai ter que implementar a lógica que verifica se o usuário já existe na base antes de inserir.

Comment: outra opção é alterar a tabela para deixar a coluna `usuario` unique, mas mesmo neste caso vai ter que tratar o erro.

Comment: Em php eu sei fazer isso , mas sou novo em nodejs , não estou conseguindo implementar a logica , alguem teria um exemplo por favor!

Comment: em PHP ficaria assim 

   $busca = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Usuario='$usuario'");
    $existe = mysqli_num_rows($busca);

    if($existe == 0) {
        mysqli_query($mysqli

Comment: Basicamente o que vai precisar fazer é encadear as chamadas, tem um exemplo nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/505492/103217)

Comment: Acho que vou criar uma api no php e fazer por get no node, realmente nao consegui fazer funcionar :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira direta de resolver o problema seria apenas refatorar o seu código para que implementasse esta lógica.

Segue um exemplo:

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  const sql_verifica_usuario = "SELECT * from user where usuario = ?";
  con.query(sql_verifica_usuario, [msg.chat.id], (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (result.length > 0) {
        console.log('Já existe um usuário com este username em nossos registros');
        //tratar o erro...
    } else {
       // inserir o usuário
    }
  })
});
```

Na parte de inserir o usuário pode utilizar o código que já desenvolveu.

Repare que no código postado possui alguns problemas, um deles é que está concatenando valores a uma string e vai executar diretamente um SQL que possui entrada provida por um usuário. Isso gera um problema de segurança e ataques do tipo sql injection. Isso já foi largamente discutido em outras postagens aqui no site. [Ref](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100729/103217).

Além de prevenir esse tipo de ataque, isso também vai evitar outro problema que existe em seu código, uma vez que você consiga colocar para funcionar o seu código vai ver que ele possui um erro pois a coluna senha não está em um formato aceitável pelo padrão SQL, se quiser terá que "adicionar" asplas simples em volta do seu SQL gerado...

A correção ficará assim:

```
  //como está:
  var sql = "INSERT INTO user (Usuario, Senha) VALUES ("+msg.chat.id + "," + msg.chat.2 + ")";
  //como deve ficar:
  var sql = "INSERT INTO user (Usuario, Senha) VALUES ("+msg.chat.id + ",'" + msg.chat['2'] + "')";
```

Desta forma o que eu sugiro fazer é utilizar uma consulta SQL parametrizada, igual fizemos no trecho de código que fazemos a verificação se o usuário já existe em nossa base.

A versão final do código ficaria a seguinte:

```
con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    const sql_verifica_usuario = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Usuario = ?";
    con.query(sql_verifica_usuario, [msg.chat.id], (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (result.length > 0) {
            //tratar o erro...
            console.log('Já existe um usuário com este username em nossos registros');
            
        } else {
            // inserir o usuário
            const sql = "INSERT INTO user (Usuario, Senha) VALUES (?,?)";
            con.query(sql, [msg.chat.id, msg.chat['2']], function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Registro inserido");
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Para utilizar uma `consulta parametrizada` basta chamar a função `query` com dois parâmetros (este segundo parâmetro é um *array* com os argumentos que deseja substituir na consulta parametrizada).

Em caso de dúvida consulte a [documentação oficial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) da biblioteca.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo , deu certinho!